# Ant, replaceregexp, match and replace specific element in the list of matches

Tags: regex, ant, match

In my ant build file, I have a task that needs to replace a specific element of a XML.

Here is the target XML that I am trying to modify:

```
<foo>
 <sub>
  <elem>name1</elem>
 </sub>
 <sub>
  <elem>name2</elem>
 </sub>
 <sub>
  <elem>name3</elem>
 </sub>
</foo>
```

Ant build task:

```
<replaceregexp file="myfoo.xml"
      match="&lt;elem&gt;(.*)elem&gt;"
      replace="&lt;elem&gt;${replace_only_second_match}elem&gt;"
      byline="true"
/>
```

The problem with the above task is that all the  tags will get replaced. However, I want only the second element to be modified, not the first or 3rd match. (such a thing is quite easy with normal regular expressions.)

Dont know how to do it with Ant's regular expression. This is where I need help/suggestions on how best to solve this problem.

Comment: Just go to http://www.oopsconsultancy.com/software/xmltask/ and search for 'withXml'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use [xmltask](http://www.oopsconsultancy.com/software/xmltask/) for xmlrelated tasks, for your problem use it like that :

Modify the file inplace

```
<xmltask source="whatever.xml" dest="whatever.xml">
  <replace path="//sub[2]/elem/text()" withText="newname2"/>
</xmltask>
```

Create new file

```
<xmltask source="whatever.xml" dest="newfile.xml">
  <replace path="//sub[2]/elem/text()" withText="newname2"/>
</xmltask>
```

The replacesection also provides `withXml / withFile / withBuffer`.
See xmltask [manual](http://www.oopsconsultancy.com/software/xmltask/) and [tutorial](https://today.java.net/pub/a/today/2006/11/01/xml-manipulation-using-xmltask.html) for details.
Some XPath essentials [here](http://www.zvon.org/xxl/XPathTutorial/General/examples.html).

Comment: Thanks. I had seen this before but did not go in that direction until you pointed. Also, I cant seem to find any reference to "withXml" or "withBuffer" in the manual.

Comment: Just go to http://www.oopsconsultancy.com/software/xmltask/ and search for 'withXml'